# Convert string list in column of Pandas data frame into mean integer

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have two data frames like the following:

```
Id    Name    Price   
1    [ABC]        33900
1    [XYZ]        33900
```

When I groupby using tolist by id, I got a list as:

```
Id   Name         Price
1    [[ABC],[XYZ]]   [33900,33900]
```

I want to convert this to single value as:

```
Id    Name     Price
1   [ABC,XYZ]   33900
```

I am not able to apply np.mean or any other operation as it is showing as list. 
Dataframe also included string which successfully grouped using tolist but integers also got added as list.

Comment: I think need `df.groupby(['Id','Price'])['Name'].apply(list)`

Comment: If want aggregate another functions like `mean` - `df.groupby('Id').agg({'Name': lambda x: x.tolist(), 'Price':'mean'})`

Comment: Jezrael solution solves it. But still strings are coming as lists e.g. `[[ABC],[XYZ]]` , is it possible to have column like `[ABC,XYZ]`

Comment: What is `print (df['Name'].head().apply(type))` ?

Comment: `0    <class 'list'>
1    <class 'list'>
2    <class 'list'>
3    <class 'list'>
4    <class 'list'>
Name: name, dtype: object`

Comment: Those are list of strings. I scrapped on news articles to produce them date wise and combined various articles date wise.

Comment: Yes, and for `Price` column need `mean` ?

Comment: Prices are same for each date, I took mean as it will come to same. Eg. [100,100,100] will be 100.. But I don't need it. I just need price.

Comment: Ok, how working `df = df.groupby(['Id','Price'])['Name'].apply(lambda x: [i for li in x for i in li])` ?

Comment: Worked. `reset_index` . Thanks !!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think need [`GroupBy.apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.apply.html) with [flattening lists](https://stackoverflow.com/a/952952):

```
df = (df.groupby(['Id','Price'])['Name']
        .apply(lambda x: [i for li in x for i in li])
        .reset_index())
print (df)
   Id  Price        Name
0   1  33900  [ABC, XYZ]
```